# Draw nickels and dollar coins until $p$ dollars, expectation

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, expected-value

Here's a question from my probability textbook:

> A bag contains $m$ dollar coins and $n$ nickels. A man is allowed to draw coins one by one until he has drawn at least $p$ dollars. Show that the value of his expectation is ${{np}\over{20(m+1)}} + p$ dollars.

Here's what I did. We space our $m$ dollar coins equally so that they partition our $n$ nickels into $m+1$ parts of ${n\over{m+1}}$ nickels each. And each of those parts will have value of ${n\over{20(m+1)}}$ dollars. So then our desired expectation ${{np}\over{20(m+1)}} + p$ dollars is equal to drawing coins up until the $p$th (evenly spaced) dollar coin.

But these are just my observations, I'm not sure if I have even showed what we wanted to show. Have I just merely asserted what we want to show without explanation? How can I conclude the result? What am I missing? Is the problem statement even correct?

**Update:** To clarify, I realize the problem statement means at least $p$ dollar coins, hence the solution method I gave and also Yuri Negometyanov's solution below. But I am more interested in the answer when it's at least $p$ dollars in money (and not at least $p$ dollar coins).

Comment: What is a nickle?

Comment: @GrahamKemp A nickel is a 5 cent coin. There are 100 cents in every dolllar.

Comment: Is the question asking for the expected value until he has drawn p dollar coins, or just p dollars in value?

Comment: $p$ dollars in value, since that's more difficult and interesting?

Comment: The question seems wrong, or I need some clarification. 
If $n = 0$ then $p$ has to be an integer for the formula to make sense. His expectation is $p$, everything is fine; but this suppose that $p$ is an integer, otherwise it should be $p+1$ and that is not the case. 
if now $m = 0$ then his expectation is again... $p$ because $p$ is an integer; and clearly  it can be divided by nickels. But this is not what the formula gives you...

Comment: I understand this as an expectation in value (i.e. what the man ends up with at the end of the game) and not in the number of times he picks a coin inside the bag. But perhaps I am mistaken ?

Comment: Are we asking about the expected number of coins or amount of money? Unless I misunderstand it, for $m=0$ , we should get $20 p$  (if coins) or $p$  (if money). But the formula does not agree. For $n=0$ it's fine either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\;P(p,q)\;$ is the possibility to get $\;p\;$ dollars and $\;q\;$ nickels of $\;(p+q)\;$ coins, when the last coin is a dollar.

Also, let $\;Q(p,q)\;$ is the possibility to get $\;p\;$ dollars and $\;q\;$ nickels of $\;(p+q)\;$ coins, when the last coin is a nickel.

Then
$$P(p,q)=\dfrac{\dbinom{m}{p-1}\dbinom{n}{q}}{\dbinom{m+n}{p+q-1}}\,\dfrac{m-p+1}{m+n-q-p+1}$$
$$=\dfrac{m-p+1}{m+n-q-p+1}\,
\dfrac{m!n!(p+q-1)!(m+n-p-q+1)!}{(p-1)!(m-p+1)!q!(n-q)!(m+n)!}$$
$$=\dfrac{m!n!(p+q-1)!(m+n-p-q)!}{(p-1)!(m-p)!q!(n-q)!(m+n)!} 
=\dfrac{\dbinom{p-1+q}{p-1}\dbinom{m+n-p-q}{m-p}}{\dbinom{m+n}{n}},\,$$
$$Q(p,q)=\dfrac{\dbinom{m}{p}\dbinom{n}{q-1}}{\dbinom{m+n}{p+q-1}} \,\dfrac{n-q+1}{m+n-p-q+1}$$
$$=\dfrac{n-q+1}{m+n-p-q+1}\,
\dfrac{m!n!(p+q-1)!(m+n-p-q+1)!}{p!(m-p)!(q-1)!(n-q+1)!(m+n)!}$$
$$=\dfrac{m!n!(p+q-1)!(m+n-p-q)!}{p!(m-p)!(q-1)!(n-q)!(m+n)!} 
=\dfrac{\dbinom{p+q-1}{q-1}\dbinom{m+n-p-k}{m-p}}{\dbinom{m+n}{n}},\,$$
$$\sum\limits_{q=0}^n P(p,q)=1$$
[image: Sum of probabilities]

and similarly
$$\sum\limits_{p=0}^m Q(p,q)=1.$$

If $\;n<20,\;$ then the expectation of the money sum is
$$E_{\tilde p}\left(p+\dfrac{q}{20}\right)= \tilde p +\dfrac1{20}\sum\limits_{q=0}^n qP(\tilde p,q)=\tilde p+\dfrac{n\tilde p}{20(m+1)}.$$

[image: Expectation]

In the common case, $\;Q(p,q)\;$ does not influence to the fractional part of the sum, and
$$E_{\tilde p}\left(p+\dfrac{q}{20}\right)= \tilde p 
+\left\{\sum\limits_{q=0}^{\min(n,10\tilde p)}\genfrac\{\}{}0q{20}P(p,q)\bigg|_{p=\tilde p- {\small\genfrac\lfloor\rfloor{}0q{20}}}\right\}.$$

Comment: Thanks @Yuri. See my update where I give some clarification as to what I'm looking for.

Comment: @EmperorConcerto Thanks! Tried to fix.